# Click language works 1 time on 3

Tags: angular, typescript

When I select a language for example `NL`, I have to click 2 times or 3 times to display the text correctly in dutch.

I don't understand why the first click doesn't work?

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLjPa.png)

**HTML**

```
<div class="languageSelect">
 <a href="#" *ngFor="let l of supportedLangs;" (click)="switchLanguage(l); false; ">
   {{ l | uppercase}}
 </a>
</div>
```

**TS**

I think that the problem is in my typescript ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-layout',
  templateUrl: './auth-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth-layout.component.scss']
})
export class AuthLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  supportedLangs;

  constructor(
    public _router: Router,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private LS: LocalStoreService,
    public _location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.supportedLangs = ['fr', 'nl', 'en', 'de', 'es', 'it', 'pt'];
  }

  switchLanguage(lang) {
    if (lang == 'uk') {
      lang = 'en';
    }

    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      this.LS.setItem('LX_Current_Language', event.lang);
    });
    this.translate.use(lang);

    this.refresh();
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this._router.navigateByUrl("/refresh", { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
      this._router.navigate([decodeURI(this._location.path())]);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you change the `a` element to `button` and remove the `href`?

Comment: I feel that you should subscribe in ngOnInit and in your function switchLanguage **only** use the `this.translate.use(lang)`, but really I don't know about your TranslateService

Comment: @eko: With the `buttons`, I always have the same problem. :-(

Comment: @Eliseo: I also have the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add change detector
like that:

**your Constructor**

```
constructor(
public _router: Router,
private translate: TranslateService,
private changeDetectoref : ChangeDetectorRef,
private LS: LocalStoreService,
public _location: Location) { }
```

**switchLanguage function**

```
switchLanguage(lang) {
if (lang == 'uk') {
  lang = 'en';
}

this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
  this.LS.setItem('LX_Current_Language', event.lang);
});
this.translate.use(lang);
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
this.refresh();}
```

Comment: Mohamed: when I click on another language, nothing happens. :-(